# Do long-haired men have better intuition?

Tags: physiology, hair

I found an article on [Worldwide Hippies](http://www.worldwidehippies.com/2013/11/12/the-truth-about-long-hair/) which describes a military experiment on the intuitive abilities of Native American trackers:

> Then they would pair two men together who had received the same scores on all the tests. They would let one man in the pair keep his hair long, and gave the other man a military haircut. Then the two men retook the tests.
>
> Time after time the man with long hair kept making high scores. Time after time, the man with the short hair failed the tests in which he had previously scored high scores.

Is this being made up?

Comment: You'd be in a crappy and nonproductive mood as well if some complete jerk just cut your hair "to test a theory".

Comment: What could this mean about bald men? Extrapolation of this could lead to dangerous places...

Comment: Sounds like the Nocebo effect- they may have had the same effect if they'd make him believe his hair had been cut but just covered it so he didn't know. It doesn't sound like they were very thorough.

Comment: I have my doubts based on `failed the tests in which he had previously scored high scores.` SO they are not talking about minor differences, they are talking about passing with flying colors to failing. That is a huge huge difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did Native American trackers lose their tracking abilities when their hair was shaved?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28805/did-native-american-trackers-lose-their-tracking-abilities-when-their-hair-was-s)